# The text is rendering clipped ignoring isStretchWithOverflow property value using PDF exporter

Tags: jasper-reports, export-to-pdf

Is it possible to wrap text in a groupHeader? I have it working in the detail section,
but the text within the group does not seem to want to wrap. I have tried every combination for wrapping I could think of or find from google.

```xml
<style name="reportProject" isDefault="false" fontName="Times" fontSize="10" isBold="false" isItalic="true" isUnderline="false" isStrikeThrough="false"/>
<group name="PROJHEADER" minHeightToStartNewPage="60">
    <groupExpression><![CDATA[$F{projectHeader}]]>
    </groupExpression>
    <groupHeader>
        <band height="40" splitType="Stretch">
            <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[Boolean.valueOf($F{projectHeader}.length() > 0)]]>
            </printWhenExpression>
            <textField  isStretchWithOverflow="true"  isBlankWhenNull="true"
                                evaluationTime="Group" evaluationGroup="PROJHEADER" bookmarkLevel="1">
                <reportElement positionType="Float" style="reportProject" mode="Opaque" x="0" y="5" 
                                width="515" height="15" backcolor="#C0C0C0"
                                stretchType="RelativeToBandHeight"/>
                <box leftPadding="10">
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Left" verticalAlignment="Middle" />
                <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[$F{projectHeader}]]>
                </textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </groupHeader>
</group>
```

Answer (score 2):

Setting the **isStretchWithOverflow** property with **true** value helps me.

The sample:

```xml
<group name="citygr">
    <groupExpression><![CDATA[$F{CITY}]]></groupExpression>
    <groupHeader>
        <band height="20">
            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true">
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="100" height="20"/>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{CITY} + " text1 txt2 longtext3 verylonglongtxt4 long1234567890verylongtext5 txt6 text6 longtext7"]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </groupHeader>
</group>
```

The result will be:

[image: The pdf report]

I'm using the ***iReport 4.1.3***.

You can also try to set **net.sf.jasperreports.export.pdf.force.linebreak.policy** property. Just add this this property in your jrxml file. You can read about this property [here](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/config.reference.html#net.sf.jasperreports.export.pdf.force.linebreak.policy).

The sample:

```xml
<jasperReport ...>
    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.pdf.force.linebreak.policy" value="true"/>
```

Comment: I already had isStretchWithOverflow = "true". I added the property and still it did not work. However, I decided to make my textElement simple like yours and it now works. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I ended up with, that works.

```
<jasperReport ...>
   <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.pdf.force.linebreak.policy" value="true"/>
   .....
    <group name="PROJHEADER" minHeightToStartNewPage="60">
        <groupExpression><![CDATA[$F{projectHeader}]]>
        </groupExpression>
        <groupHeader>
            <band height="40" splitType="Stretch">
                <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[Boolean.valueOf($F{projectHeader}.length() > 0)]]></printWhenExpression>
                <textField  isStretchWithOverflow="true"  isBlankWhenNull="true">
                    <reportElement  style="reportProject" x="0" y="5" 
                        width="400" height="15" backcolor="#C0C0C0"/>
                    <textElement textAlignment="Left" verticalAlignment="Middle" />
                    <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[$F{projectHeader}]]>
                    </textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
            </band>
        </groupHeader>
    </group>
```