# Detail's text field seems to have a characters limit and stops stretching

Tags: jasper-reports, export-to-pdf

I have four reports that are basically different formats of the same report and the following problem happens with three of them. I have a text field in the Detail's band that is marked as ***Stretch with Overflow***. The problem is that it seems that it has some kind of characters limit, because with the following text (110 characters):

```
MAD.ESP.TAUARI(COURATARI GUIANENSIS AUBL.)SERRADA EM RIPA.KD.FAS.FSC 100% MED.19,1MMX38,1MMX2438,4MM DE COMP.
```

It's only printing:

```
MAD.ESP.TAUARI(COURATARI GUIANENSIS AUBL.)SERRADA EM RIPA.KD.FAS.FSC 100% MED.19,1MMX38,1MMX2438,4MM DE
```

As shown in the screen shots:

[image: First report]
[image: Second report]
[image: Third report (only one printing correctly)]
[image: Fourth report]

It's woth noting that when using the "preview" of the JasperStudio, the whole text appears normally for all of them.

Here's the text field's code of one of them. They're basically the same, changing the width, height and position.

```
<textField isStretchWithOverflow="true">
    <reportElement x="26" y="0" width="76" height="10">
    </reportElement>
    <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Top">
        <font fontName="Arial" size="8"/>
    </textElement>
    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{descricaoProduto}]]></textFieldExpression>
</textField>
```

I'm using the 6.2.2 version of JasperReports.

EDIT:

I created a gist with a minimal version of the report that the problem happens:

[Sample](https://gist.github.com/fernandocamargoti/3a62d6ec1d3142bc44e53c67c9d6d7a4)

I'm exporting it to PDF and using Arial as the font (I added a JAR with the Arial font).

Comment: You should post the small sample (*jrxml*) to reproduce the problem. What is an output format? Did you try to use different fonts?

Comment: @AlexK, I just added a minimal sample. I haven't tried other fonts yet.

Comment: Setting net.sf.jasperreports.export.pdf.force.linebreak.policy to true might help.  See http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/config.reference.html#net.sf.jasperreports.export.pdf.force.linebreak.policy

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Text wrap in Group Header (or Footer) using PDF export](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8919645/text-wrap-in-group-header-or-footer-using-pdf-export) & [text wrapping issue in pdf export in Ireport 4.0.2](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7964833/876298)

Comment: @FernandoCamargo Solution by data67 works like a charm :)

Comment: @dada67, your solution worked for me! You may create an answer with it for me to accept and upvote.

Comment: @FernandoCamargo It is better to mark your question as duplicate - you can accept from your side

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the `net.sf.jasperreports.export.pdf.force.linebreak.policy` property to `true` (in jasperreports.properties or programmatically). See http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/config.reference.html#net.sf.jasperreports.export.pdf.force.linebreak.policy

The property instructs the PDF exporter to use `java.text.BreakIterator` to determine where line breaks can occur in texts, which ensures that the line breaks at PDF export time match the breaks uses when the text was measured at report fill time.  As a note, this might come with some impact on PDF exporting performance, but it shouldn't be dramatic.